# How can I configure Docker login on Kubernetes nodes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Is this the right method to configure a Docker login on Kubernetes nodes or do I need to enter on all nodes and make a Docker login?

```
cd ~/apache
export DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER=hub.docker.com
export DOCKER_USER=xxxxx
export DOCKER_PASSWORD=mypassword
export DOCKER_EMAIL=andrea.ciuffoli@xxxx.com
.
kubectl create secret docker-registry cfcr  --docker-server=$DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER --docker-username=$DOCKER_USER --docker-password=$DOCKER_PASSWORD --docker-email=$DOCKER_EMAIL
```

Output:

```
secret/cfcr created
```

And inside the YAML content, add these three lines:

```
...
livenessProbe:
    httpGet:
      path: /
          port: 80
        initialDelaySeconds: 5
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: cfcr
```

Comment: Are you getting any specific errors with this?

Answer (score 2):

Solved with:

```
docker login
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/ubuntu/.docker/config.json.


kubectl create secret generic cfcr  --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=/home/ubuntu/.docker/config.json  --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

and the same lines in the .yaml

Comment: Hello. Does 'cfcr' have any special meaning or is it arbitrary?

Comment: What is *"risolto con"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I have just translated that phrase, in an edit.